# How to use Django template tags inside Java Script without for loop

Tags: javascript, python, django

I want to use template variable inside JavaScript :
My problem is using for loop inside the javascript code is every thing between for loop is going to repeat .. But i don't want that....Below i have pasted my code ..Can anybody tell me the better way of doing this....because this looks ugly..

Here is my code:

```
    {% block extra_javascript %}
    <script src="/static/js/Chart.min.js"></script> 
    <script>    
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var data = {
    labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"],
    datasets : [
        {
            fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",

                      data : [{{ stats_dict.0.Jan }},{{ stats_dict.1.Feb }},{{ stats_dict.2.March }},{{ stats_dict.3.April }}
                      ,{{ stats_dict.4.May }},{{ stats_dict.5.June }},{{ stats_dict.6.July }},{{ stats_dict.7.August }},{{ stats_dict.8.Sept }},
                      {{ stats_dict.9.Oct }},{{ stats_dict.10.Nov }},{{ stats_dict.11.Dec }}]                     


        }
    ]
};
    //Get context with jQuery - using jQuery's .get() method.
    var ctx = $("#myChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
    //This will get the first returned node in the jQuery collection.
    var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx).Bar(data,{});
    });
  </script>
  {% endblock %}
```

Context :

```
[[{'stats_dict': [{'Jan': 0}, {'Feb': 0}, {'March': 0}, {'April': 0}, {'May': 0}, {'June': 0}, {'July': 0}, {'August': 0}, {'Sept': 3}, {'Oct': 0}, {'Nov': 0}, {'Dec': 0}]}], {'csrf_token': <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0xa4d874c>}, {'perms': <django.contrib.auth.context_processors.PermWrapper object at 0xa4d878c>, 'user': <django.utils.functional.SimpleLazyObject object at 0xa47abcc>}, {}, {'LANGUAGES': (('ar', 'Arabic'), ('az', 'Azerbaijani'), ('bg', 'Bulgarian'), ('bn', 'Bengali'), ('bs', 'Bosnian'), ('ca', 'Catalan'), ('cs', 'Czech'), ('cy', 'Welsh'), ('da', 'Danish'), ('de', 'German'), ('el', 'Greek'), ('en', 'English'), ('en-gb', 'British English'), ('eo', 'Esperanto'), ('es', 'Spanish'), ('es-ar', 'Argentinian Spanish'), ('es-mx', 'Mexican Spanish'), ('es-ni', 'Nicaraguan Spanish'), ('et', 'Estonian'), ('eu', 'Basque'), ('fa', 'Persian'), ('fi', 'Finnish'), ('fr', 'French'), ('fy-nl', 'Frisian'), ('ga', 'Irish'), ('gl', 'Galician'), ('he', 'Hebrew'), ('hi', 'Hindi'), ('hr', 'Croatian'), ('hu', 'Hungarian'), ('id', 'Indonesian'), ('is', 'Icelandic'), ('it', 'Italian'), ('ja', 'Japanese'), ('ka', 'Georgian'), ('kk', 'Kazakh'), ('km', 'Khmer'), ('kn', 'Kannada'), ('ko', 'Korean'), ('lt', 'Lithuanian'), ('lv', 'Latvian'), ('mk', 'Macedonian'), ('ml', 'Malayalam'), ('mn', 'Mongolian'), ('nb', 'Norwegian Bokmal'), ('ne', 'Nepali'), ('nl', 'Dutch'), ('nn', 'Norwegian Nynorsk'), ('pa', 'Punjabi'), ('pl', 'Polish'), ('pt', 'Portuguese'), ('pt-br', 'Brazilian Portuguese'), ('ro', 'Romanian'), ('ru', 'Russian'), ('sk', 'Slovak'), ('sl', 'Slovenian'), ('sq', 'Albanian'), ('sr', 'Serbian'), ('sr-latn', 'Serbian Latin'), ('sv', 'Swedish'), ('sw', 'Swahili'), ('ta', 'Tamil'), ('te', 'Telugu'), ('th', 'Thai'), ('tr', 'Turkish'), ('tt', 'Tatar'), ('uk', 'Ukrainian'), ('ur', 'Urdu'), ('vi', 'Vietnamese'), ('zh-cn', 'Simplified Chinese'), ('zh-tw', 'Traditional Chinese')), 'LANGUAGE_BIDI': False, 'LANGUAGE_CODE': 'en-us'}, {'MEDIA_URL': ''}, {'STATIC_URL': '/static/'}, {'TIME_ZONE': 'America/Chicago'}, {'messages': <django.contrib.messages.storage.fallback.FallbackStorage object at 0xa47ac6c>}]
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what is inside `stats_dict`. Could you show the Python that gives it context, or show it printed out?

Comment: I want know better way of doing what i have done above....If i use for loop to get the stats_dict value the whole java script will repeat 12 time and i don't want that ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step 1 - Never **EVER** mix JavaScript and Django template language. It's a setup for disaster.

Step 2 - Refactor

Refactor first step:

Create a new view that outputs a JSON'd dict of dates. (I'm not coding your application but I'll give you the pointers on how to improve)

```
def date_view(request):
    stats = Stats.objects.all().order_by('month')
    #do some other stuff that you already have done.
    return {'january':stats.january, and so forth...}
```

Step b) - Refactor your current code to something along the lines of this:

```
var dataForChart =  {
  labels: [months],
  datasets: [{
    fillColor: ...,
    strokeColor: ...,
    data: null,
  }]
}

$.get('/myStatsViewUrl', function(data) {
  dataForChart["data"] = data;
});
```

Step c)
Rejoice that you now have decoupled Djangos template from your javascript and much rejoicing was done 'cause you can now reuse it anywhere in your code!

Comment: You could use [rest-framework](http://django-rest-framework.org/) for serialized views

Comment: @kroolik Yeah, definately, but I don't think it's the best idea for his issues atm.